# While we are uploading file(s) to notes & attachments, I want to show the progress bar( 0% to 100%). Is it possible in salesforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery

---

For UI I will use jQuery progress bar.Depending upon the uploading speed, progress bar will respond slowly/quickly. How do we estimate the time dynamically and integrate with progress bar?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, attach a [progress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/progress) event to your [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object, and every time you get some progress, you can calculate the percentage. The estimated time remaining is naively implemented as (now - startTime) * (1 - percentage); in other words, find out how much percentage remains and multiply that by the amount of time already elapsed. As far as a jQuery specific example, you can read blog entries [like this one](http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/), which includes some code snippets:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/",
  data: {},
  beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    //Upload progress
    XMLHttpRequest.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {  
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        //Do something with upload progress
      }
    }, false); 
    //Download progress
    XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {  
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        //Do something with download progress
      }
    }, false); 
  },
  success: function(data){
    //Do something success-ish
  }
});
```

Simply set the start time in the beforeSend function, and you can calculate the remaining amount from the progress events.